# How do I correctly add a HashTable to a JSON file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have this hashtable:

```
$a = @{
"computer1" = @{
    "app1" = "2023.04.04"
    "app2" = "2022.07.11"
}}
```

How do I add it to a file: `$jsonReportPath = "./report.json"`? Assume the JSON file doesn't exist before the adding operation.
I need to make that into a function that would take a hashtable as an argument and would add it to a JSON file in case if the key of that hashtable ("computer1" is the key here) is not already present in that JSON file.

Note that I do not want to replace the existing content in the JSON file, I just want to add to it one more hashtable.

So if the JSON report file looks this way:

```
{
  "computer": {
    "program": "22.9.0.135",
    "program1": "4.0.1.23758"
  },
  "computer0": {
    "program": "22.5.0.135",
    "program1": "4.7.1.23758"
  }
}
```

, after adding another hashtable to it, it will look this way:

```
{
  "computer": {
    "program": "22.9.0.135",
    "program1": "4.0.1.23758"
  },
  "computer0": {
    "program": "22.5.0.135",
    "program1": "4.7.1.23758"
  },
  "computer1": {
    "app1": "2023.04.04",
    "app2": "2022.07.11"
  }
}
```

Here's the function that I came up with:

```
function AddItemToJsonReport([Hashtable]$item) {
    $jsonReportPath = "C:\path\to\json\report.json"
    $report = Get-Content -Path $jsonReportPath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
    if (-not $report) {
        $report = @{}
    } # If the json report is empty, initialize it as an empty hashtable
    $nodeName = $item.PSObject.Properties.Name # Get the key of the hashtable, the node name
    # If the node already exists in the json report, don't add it again
    if ($report.ContainsKey($nodeName)) { return }
    $item.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $report[$.Key] = $.Value
    }
    $updatedJsonReport = ConvertTo-Json $report -Depth 100
    $fileExists = Test-Path $jsonReportPath
    if ($fileExists) {
        Out-File -FilePath $jsonReportPath -InputObject $updatedJsonReport -Encoding utf8
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there's a better, more 'proper' way of doing it. My solution seems a little bit of an overkill for this kind of problem.

Comment: And how have you tried to solve the problem? Please add your coding attempt

Comment: Your code is pretty close and seems like a good approach, you definitely don't need `$nodeName = $item.PSObject.Properties.Name`, hashtables have a `.Keys` property and you should also do the `$report.ContainsKey(..)` while looping the `$item` keys in case youre about to add 2 or more objects to the json

Comment: Going forward, please include all relevant information when writing a question

Comment: I don't think you need to delete your answer, you're showing a different take on how to do it and that is fine. If you decide to undelete it I'll upvote it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you, Santiago, I undeleted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks pretty good to me, there are a few things that could be simplified. Needles to say, this code assumes you're using **PowerShell 6+**.

```bash
function Add-ItemToJsonReport {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Hashtable] $Items,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [string] $Path = 'C:\path\to\json\report.json'
    )

    $report = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

    if (-not $report) {
        $report = @{}
    }

    $Items.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        # if the Json already has this property
        if($report.ContainsKey($_.Key)) {
            # go to the next key / value pair
            return
        }

        $report[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    }

    $report | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 |
        Set-Content $Path -Encoding utf8
}
```

Using the Json provided in question, with the following function call:

```bash
Add-ItemToJsonReport -Items @{
    ComputerTest = 'foo', 'baz'
    # note `computer` in lower-case (-AsHashtable) produces a case-sensitive hash
    computer0    = 'this one is already added'
    ComputerFoo  = 'hello world'
}
```

The resulting Json would become:

```json
{
  "computer": {
    "program": "22.9.0.135",
    "program1": "4.0.1.23758"
  },
  "computer0": {
    "program": "22.5.0.135",
    "program1": "4.7.1.23758"
  },
  "ComputerTest": [
    "foo",
    "baz"
  ],
  "ComputerFoo": "hello world"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly where you asked for but at least a direction you might look in to given that you are appearently in control of the design of the Json file...

A more common way to do this, is to create arrays with single elements (hashtables or [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)s), knowing that a hashtable itself requires unique keys:

```
$Computers =
@{
    program  = "22.9.0.135"
    program1 = "4.0.1.23758"
},
@{
    program = "22.5.0.135"
    program1 = "4.7.1.23758"
},
@{
    app1 = "2023.04.04"
    app2 = "2022.07.11"
}
$Report = @{}
$Report.Computers = $Computers.Foreach{ @(@{ Computer = $_ }) }
```

In that case your Json will look like:

```
$Json = $Report |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
$Json

{
  "Computers": [
    {
      "Computer": {
        "program": "22.9.0.135",
        "program1": "4.0.1.23758"
      }
    },
    {
      "Computer": {
        "program": "22.5.0.135",
        "program1": "4.7.1.23758"
      }
    },
    {
      "Computer": {
        "app1": "2023.04.04",
        "app2": "2022.07.11"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that each node in the `computers` list is just called `computer`.
Where you might than use [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) to retrieve the properties:

```
$Report = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
$Report.Computers.Computer.Program1
4.0.1.23758
4.7.1.23758

$Report.Computers.Computer
Name                           Value
----                           -----
program                        22.9.0.135
program1                       4.0.1.23758
program                        22.5.0.135
program1                       4.7.1.23758
app1                           2023.04.04
app2                           2022.07.11
```

To write (update) a specific property, you might do so by using the specific index, e.g.:

```
$Report.Computers.Computer[1].Program1 = '1.2.3.4'

$Report.Computers.Computer.Program1
4.0.1.23758
1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me based on the comment from @Santiago Squarzon:

```
function Add-ItemToJsonReport([hashtable]$item) {
    $report = Get-Content -Path $jsonReportPath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
    if (-not $report) {
        $report = @{}
    } # if the JSON report is empty, initialize it as an empty hashtable

    foreach ($key in $item.Keys) {
        # if the node already exists in the JSON report, don't add it again
        if (-not $report.ContainsKey($key)) {
            $report[$key] = $item[$key]
        }
    }

    $updatedJsonReport = ConvertTo-Json $report -Depth 100
    Out-File -FilePath $jsonReportPath -InputObject $updatedJsonReport -Encoding utf8
}
```